# How to relocate Form region in outlook using c# VSTO?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have added an Adjoining-Form Region to my plugin, so when you open a Meeting, it will append the Form Region to the bottom of the Meeting screen.

This all seems to work fine. But I want to relocate the form region between 'End Time' and the TextBox of the meeting or beside the date and time.

https://i.imgsafe.org/5ca8e87d2c.png - Current FormRegion position
https://i.imgsafe.org/5cb109ae04.png - Required FormRegion position

Is it possible to change the position of Form Region?
I am using MS Outlook 2016 and Visual Studio 2015.

Can someone please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Can't do that.

The best you can do is some HWND level magic. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook/